# Reading accurate sleeping data from Google Fit API

Tags: android, api, kotlin, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am currently developing an app that will get Fitness History Data from Google Fit. Getting the steps and weight are okay but getting the sleep data is a bit of a problem. I want to get the accurate start and end time but the only way to get that is to bucket it by activity segment. The problem is, when there's a lot of data you are trying to get (the app that I'm currently developing requires to get data from 365 days ago at the most), it will not even return a timeout error and my app will keep loading. It will not even start to read the data from Google Fit. So, I wanna ask if there's a way to get the sleep data by activity segment despite its large size? And please do share your code. And by the way, this is how I get my sleep data:

```
val sleepReadRequest = DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
        .bucketByActivitySegment(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .setTimeRange(offset, end, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build()

    LogUtil.d(TAG, "getting sleep data...")

    Fitness.getHistoryClient(
        context,
        Objects.requireNonNull<GoogleSignInAccount>(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context))
    )
        .readData(sleepReadRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener { dataReadResponse ->
            LogUtil.d(TAG, "success sleep data")
            val secondSet = handleDataReturned(dataReadResponse, false, DateUtil.convertTimeStampToDate(offset, DateUtil.DATE_FORMAT))
            dailyData.addAll(secondSet)
            val allDailyList = getDailyDataList(dailyData, userHeight)
            callback.onGetDataSuccess(allDailyList)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            LogUtil.d(TAG, "fail sleep data")
            if (e is ApiException && e.statusCode == GoogleFitError.NOT_SIGNED.code) { // not signed app exception
                revokePermission(context)
                callback.onGetDataFailure(GoogleFitError.parse(e.statusCode))
            } else {
                callback.onGetDataFailure(AppError.parse(Throwable(e)))
            }
        }
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            LogUtil.d(TAG, "complete sleep data")
            callback.onGetDataComplete(task)
        }
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you find the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than aggregating, can you just read the activity segments and iterate through them yourself?

```
val sleepReadRequest =
    DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .read(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
        .setTimeRange(offset, end, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build()
```

You can then retrieve the returned data with `DataReadResult#getDataSet(DataType)`.

If you find that it's timing out (a year of data at once is potentially rather a lot!) I'd suggest batching the request into smaller ones and caching data in the past which is unlikely to change.